# Error when HX711_Arduino_Library installed

Tags: library

First I'm getting this error #include  no such directory. Then HX711_Arduino_Library installed. Now getting following errors:
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 7), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4M (no SPIFFS), v2 Higher Bandwidth, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"
sketch_jul18a:34:22: error: no matching function for call to 'HX711::HX711(int, int)'HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);
                      ^
C:\Users\My Lappy\Desktop\sketch_jul18a\sketch_jul18a.ino:34:22: note: candidates are:In file included from C:\Users\My Lappy\Desktop\sketch_jul18a\sketch_jul18a.ino:23:0:
C:\Users\MyLappy\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HX711_Arduino_Library\src/HX711.h:30:3: note: HX711::HX711()
   HX711();
   ^
C:\Users\MyLappy\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HX711_Arduino_Library\src/HX711.h:30:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
C:\Users\MyLappy\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HX711_Arduino_Library\src/HX711.h:19:7: note: constexpr HX711::HX711(const HX711&)
 class HX711
       ^
C:\Users\MyLappy\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HX711_Arduino_Library\src/HX711.h:19:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'HX711::HX711(int, int)'

Help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several HX711 Arduino libraries. Do you have the right one? I would guess no as the library you have installed does not have the constructor that the sketch is using. Either use the correct constructor from the installed library or install another library that has that constructor.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm Not much familiar with Arduino software. can u plz help me with easy way..?? library with constructor not getting this??

Comment: Check the file HX711_Arduino_Library\src/HX711.h and the HX711 instance in your sketch. Use the constructor that matches the library. Change: sketch_jul18a:34:22: HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);

Comment: I have Checked the file HX711_Arduino_Library\src/HX711.h but not getting this Change: sketch_jul18a:34:22: HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK); with what I have to replace this..????

Comment: Start with the example sketch: https://github.com/bogde/HX711/blob/master/examples/HX711_basic_example/HX711_basic_example.ino

Comment: yes sir,  github.com/bogde/HX711/blob/master/examples/HX711_basic_example/ this link code running properly. getting this message Done compiling without any error. But for my code still getting same error message: no matching function for call to 'HX711::HX711(int, int)'.. Guide me for next step to solve this issue.

Comment: Please post your sketch and we will help you fix it.

Comment: Not able to post my sketch its too long.. what can I do now?

Comment: Locate the line that starts with HX711 and remove the parameters to the constructor. Add a line to the setup() the calls HX711::begin() with the pin parameters. And now you should mark the question as answered :)